# Autosar Client Server configuration problem

Tags: embedded, autosar, automotive

I'm trying to configure a Client server interface for 3 operations in AUTOSAR 4.2 using EB tresos tool.
I have configure the required P and R ports in the in Server and Client respectively.
I have created 3 runnables and Operation invoked event for Server and CS interface in Client.

error 1: Im getting an issue that the runnable in server component refer to R port in Client and that its only valid if runnable and R port are in the same component.

error 2: If I put the runnables and Operation invoked event in the Client I get the error that the P port in the server points to an interface not mapped by any operation invoked event

Any one have an idea on how to

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand what you are doing, but the Server Runnable can only be triggered by the Provider-Port of the (Server) component (not the R-Port in the client)

Comment: Yes That is my understanding as well, but the error was reported by the tool. If I create the runnable and Oie(Operation invoked event) in the server component I get an error 1 if I put it in Client component I get error 2. I have attached the picture depicting the configuration that I have done as reference now.

Comment: again, the operation invoke event can only be related to the Provider-Port. In your picture you have some red arrow from the runnable to the R-Port. That is wrong.
I am afraid that your questions cannot be answered here and that you would need some basic training on this topic.

Comment: Hi Got the problem there needed to be a runnable (without server call point). After this the problem got fixed and the code got generated successfully. So basically two runnable's were required one from Client side and another from server side

Answer (score 1):

Steps required:

1. If not already done, create a Port Interface having the three operations
2. If not already done, add two Software Components
3. Add a Runnable to the Software Component intended to be the server
4. Add a (Provider/ Server) Port Prototype to the Software Component intended to be the server, typed by the Port Interface
5. Add a Operation Invocation Event to trigger the Runnable when an Operation on the Port gets called
6. I guess, but I am not sure right now, whether you also have to add a Port Access  for the Runnable to the Port Prototype, or whether this happens implicitly/ automatically
7. Add a Runnable to the Software Component intended to be the server or select an existing one, which is intended to use the (Receiver/ Client) Port Prototype
8. Add a (Receiver/ Client) Port Prototype to the Software Component intended to be the client, typed by the Port Interface
9. Add a Port Access to this Runnable, so it is allowed to use the Port Prototype